# How to effectively scale Websocket servers?

Tags: websocket, architecture, scalability, publish-subscribe, event-bus

So, let's consider group of Websocket applications. Each user is connected to one of these servers. I need to implement chat application, in which each user can send  message to any user.

I am looking for fast, reliable, scalable approach, how to do it.

I think, that I need some good implementation of `event bus`. Each user, when he connects to websocket, has to be registered (or subscribed) in event bus. Then, when some another user sends message to given user, `event bus` publish message to given user.

So, what event bus should I use?

Of course, I know about [Redis Pub/Sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub), but I am not sure, that this is the best option in 2019 year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis Pub/Sub is a really good option. One thing you need to actually worry about is the number of connection limit in certain scenarios. Since you know WebSockets are long-lived connections, load balancing of this thing works little different then Http. I suggest you read this thing I am sure you will find some good resources for this.